# VueJS input checkbox and class change requires two times click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I created a list of items with checkbox. When I click on the checkbox it should tick the checkbox and add the class to the div.

However clicking on the checkbox only ticks checkbox and i need to click it again for the class to be changed.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':todo.completed}">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="todo.completed" v-on:change="markComplete">
         {{todo.title}}
    </p>
</div>
```

And the method

```
 methods: {
        markComplete() {
            this.todo.completed = !this.todo.completed
        }
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You model the value "`completed`" to the checkbox **AND** change it during `onChange`, this changes the value twice per click.

Try:

```
<div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':todo.completed}">
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="todo.completed">
        {{todo.title}}
    </p>
</div>
```

ang get rid of the function.